# virt-install - internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor, symlink to /var

Tags: mount, kvm-virtualization, symbolic-link

TLDR: when contents of /var is stored in a normal directory, virt-install works.  When /var is a symlink pointing somewhere else, virt-install breaks.

New installation of Ubuntu 14.04. 2 logical HDDs, dual quad core processors, 32G ram

I moved /var, /home, and /tmp to the second hard drive via symlinks (as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47222/how-to-mount-multiple-directories-on-the-same-partition) - `[/]#ln -s /mnt/cciss/c0d1/var var`). Since I didn't want to define separate mountable partitions for each of the directories; I wanted them all to just share that storage space.

When I run virt-install, the host throws the error:

```
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
```

using the -d option,

```
[Mon, 19 Oct 2015 16:21:16 virt-install 2921] ERROR (cli:445) internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
[Mon, 19 Oct 2015 16:21:16 virt-install 2921] DEBUG (cli:448)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virt-install", line 636, in start_install
    noboot=options.noreboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1246, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1314, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3202, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
[Mon, 19 Oct 2015 16:21:16 virt-install 2921] DEBUG (cli:457) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
```

Because I've used this tool in the past successfully, and I know I mucked about with /var, I moved the contents back to a normal /var directory. Then, things worked again.  So, somehow the fact that I've moved /var contents to another drive and symlinked it is breaking things.  Perhaps I should simply try with bind mounts? (I haven't tried that yet)

Comment: While still intriguing, this does work by using bind mounts.